# String parameter is ignored if numeric, why?

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, parameter-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am requesting a string parameter from the parameter server in ROS Groovy like this:

```
ros::NodeHandle node_ns("~");
std::string rotations;
node_ns.param<std::string>("rotations", rotations, std::string("0"));
```

When I run my ROS node with the following command line, everything works fine:

```
./bin/testnode _rotations:='90 -90 0'
```

i.e. if I check the value of the string "rotations", it is "90 -90 0". However, if I only input a single numeric value as the string's value,

```
./bin/testnode _rotations:='270'
```

the supplied value is ignored and "rotations" has its default value of "0". I think this occurs because the single value is treated as an integer instead of a string. Is this a bug? This can have pretty nasty consequences! I was debugging my code for over an hour trying to figure out why my supplied parameter value was being ignored although it had worked perfectly in other cases...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/77591/string-parameter-is-ignored-if-numeric,-why?/) by [timm](https://answers.ros.org/users/6556/timm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 376 on 2013-09-09

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have not yet had the chance to try this out, but using !!str on the command line should enforce the argument to be treated as a string, as described [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/YAMLCommandLine#Command-line_and_Strings):

> YAML uses "tags" to override types, where the YAML syntax may be ambiguous. Common tags are: !!str, !!int, !!float, !!seq and !!map. Most likely you will just need to know about !!str. YAML tags are difficult because ! has its own meaning in Bash, so you have to use single-quotes.

e.g.

```
./bin/testnode _rotations:='!!str 270'
./bin/testnode _rotations:='!!str 90 -90 0'
```

---

Originally posted by [timm](https://answers.ros.org/users/6556/timm/) with karma: 376 on 2013-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would guess that '270' is interpreted as a character. Try running

```
 ./bin/testnode _rotations:="270"
```

to tell your command line to interpret it as a string

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-09-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1